# drop-down list showing values multiple times

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a array in php - [array](http://pastebin.com/cdvsD8mz) and I am using the follwing code to create a drop-down list for this array -

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<select name="feature" id="Feature">
        <?php
        $i=0;
        foreach($newFeature as $feat)
        {
            ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $feat;?>"><?php echo $newFeature[$i];?></option>
            <?php
        $i++;
       }
         ?>
</select> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Test">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The drop-down list contains values twice. Here after traversing the array once and showing the values, code again traverse the value and show them again.

what I am doing wrong here ?
please guide.

Comment: where you have defined $newFeature???

Comment: it is an array [newFeature](http://pastebin.com/cdvsD8mz)

Comment: Ok, but where is it? also, what's the point of using a foreach if you're using an index $i? Unless $newFeature is a dimensional array (and, in this case, you're not even accessing it properly if it's a dimensional array), you're printing TWICE the same value, since $feat is the same as $newFeature[$i]

Comment: try with print_r($newFeature); and check whether the array itself contains same value twice..

Comment: newFeature is the link .. when u will click on it you ll see the array

Comment: @Jenz - array does not contain the value twice.

Comment: can you show the array???

Comment: array output link - (http://pastebin.com/cdvsD8mz)

Answer (score 1):

In my hopinion, you have a little bit confused the foreach with the for loop.

In you case, saying $newFeature[$i] or $feat is actually refering to the same thing.

Therefore, try this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<select name="feature" id="Feature">
        <?php
        foreach($newFeature as $feat)
        {
            ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $feat;?>"><?php echo $feat;?></option>
            <?php
       }
         ?>
</select> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Test">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Show us the $newFeature array. Also, why do you need the $i variable?

```
$newFeature[$i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more cleaner way to generate the list, also you are using for each in a wrong way.

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <select name="feature" id="Feature">
    <?php foreach($newFeature as $feat): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $feat; ?>"><?php echo $feat; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Test">            
</form>
```

Comment: you can try to use the function array_unique(), anyway this shouldn't be needed if the array is the one you posted. 

    foreach(array_unique($newFeature) as $feat)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `foreach` no need for counting and you should use `$feat` instead

```
<?php
foreach($newFeature as $feat)
{
    ?>
<option value="<?php echo $feat;?>"><?php echo $feat;?></option>
    <?php
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using $newFeature[$i] is a wrong way of using foreach loop.
please post a snapshot of the array or try the following.

To debug and rectify the issue

1. Print the $newFeatures array before using the foreach and debug the code.

   Or

2.Add the following line in front of the foreach loop

```
<?php $newFeature = array_unique($newFeature); ?>
```

This way might solve your problem. I still recommend you to use the first suggestion and debug your code.